# About the Yii 1.2 Framework

Tags: java, php, yii

i have the question about how to call the Controller for View.
I want to do upload my Picture to my host. i created the model upload with the name upload.php and put in model folder. like this "\protected\models"

> ```
> <?php class Upload extends CActiveRecord {
> public $image;
> // ... other attributes
>
> public function rules()
> {
>     return array(
>         array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'safe' => false),
>     );
> } }
> ```

then i made the Controller with the name UploadController.php and put in  Controller folder. "\controllers\admin".

```js
<?php class UploadController extends Controller
{
 public $layout='//content';
 
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Upload;
        if(isset($_POST['Upload']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Upload'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
            {
                $model->image->saveAs('/../themes/default/images/shopimg');
                // redirect to success page
            }
        }
        $this->render('/admin/upload', array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
```

then made the view like this with name upload.php and put it in view folder

```js
<div class="note">
 <div class="note_title">
  <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->homeUrl; ?>admin">Admin area</a> &rarr; Add Picture
 </div>
 <div class="note_body">
  <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('message')) echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('message'); ?>
  <?php $form = $this->beginWidget(
  'CActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'upload-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )
);
  ?>   
 <div class="form"><?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?></div>
  <table class="table_info"> 
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image');?></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');?></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error($model, 'image');?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');?></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

then in my main page main.php i call that upload action with this code

```html
    <td>
     <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->homeUrl; ?>admin/upload"><p>Items Upload</p>
     Items Upload</a>
    </td>
```

but it not working i don't know what i missing ! i alway said 
"Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "upload". " what that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

In yii url format will be based on controller and action.

Ex:- Controller name is UploadController and action is Create then url should be upload/create

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->homeUrl; ?>upload/create"><p>Items Upload</p>Items Upload</a>
```

if your controller is inside any module then url should be module_name/controller_name/action_name.